# DWT Page Template Title Syntax

Tags: templating, dwt

An easy few points for someone, I hope!

I want to get the Page Template title in my DWT template. I could knock up a quick C# TBB, but it seems like I should be able to do it without.

I have tried:

```
@@Page.PageTemplate.Title@@

@@Page.Template.Title@@
```

and many more permutations.

Hopefully I am missing the obvious.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Found it!

```
@@Template.Title@@
```

Thanks for listening :)

Comment: Premptive +1 for answering for future you and future others. :-)

Comment: Yea! I know I will search for this again, and find my own question :)

Comment: The explanation as to why you couldn't find it initially is, that you were trying to see the Page Template as part of the Page (in the TOM .NET API, Page.PageTemplate would make sense) but in Dreamweaver Templating, it is of course a separate object, next to that, it is the thing which renders the current Page, hence `Template.Title`