# Get PageTemplateName at DWT

Tags: 2011, dwt

I refereed below link to get pageTemplate name at DWT level. 
[DWT Page Template Title Syntax](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/1646/dwt-page-template-title-syntax)
but i am not able to get the page template name.
I am using Tridion 2011 .please let me know what else i can change to get this information.
I am getting Page information in Template builder.

Comment: Can you describe what you have, and what you have done so far?

Comment: you should share your code of DWT and what all permutation and combinations of code you have used so far

Comment: Without more information, this is just a duplicate of the question you've linked to.

Comment: I am trying to access "page template name" in the same Page Template DWT's . i tried which is described in http://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/1646/dwt-page-template-title-syntax post . but, i am getting blank instead of Template name.

Comment: I am using Tridion 2011 . is there any settings i have to do to get this information. other then this i will appreciate if any body can guide me to fetch the page template name from Tridion_Broker database